# Creating a custom preference page that syncs to SF

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, contactbuilder, preference-center

We would like to develop a custom preference page to handle subscription lists for both email and mobile.
Those subscription lists for each subscriber should be synced to SF lead/contact record as well (in both directions).

In order to implement this we thought of creating a SF field for each subscription list while populating a DE in MC that contains all contacts/leads with the necessary fields (each one of the field represent a subscription list).

The problem is that we're planning to have at least 10 subscription lists and these will make us create lots of new fields in SF for both contact and lead objects. Is there an alternative way or best practice to achieve this?

Many thanks,

Barak

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as mentioned by Eliot [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/289757/custom-profile-center-code-along-with-admin-page-in-sfmc-documentation-clarifica/289759#289759), you can create a separate Salesforce Campaign to represent each subscription type, for example:

1. Campaign for "Newsletter"
2. Campaign for "Offers"
3. Campaign for "Events"

For subscribers who have opted in, add them as Campaign Members. If they opt-out or unsubscribe completely, you can use a custom Campaign Member status like "Opted-out" and "Unsubscribed".

You will need to remember about those statuses when creating reports or sending to campaigns - remember to only include Campaign Member with status != "Opted-out" or "Unsubscribed".

For a reference on creating a Salesforce-integrated subscription centre which uses regular fields like in your original idea, take a look [here](https://sfmarketing.cloud/2020/01/14/custom-profile-and-subscription-center-integrated-with-sales-service-cloud/).